# System.Text.Json serialize derived class property

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

I'm migrating a project from `Newtonsoft.Json` to `System.Text.Json` in .NET 5.

I have class:

```cs
abstract class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Default Car Name";
}

class Tesla : Car
{
    public string TeslaEngineName { get; set; } = "My Tesla Engine";
}
```

I tried:

```cs
var cars = new List<Car> 
{ 
    new Tesla(),
    new Tesla(),
    new Tesla()
};

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(cars);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

The output is:

```json
[
  {"Name":"Default Car Name"},
  {"Name":"Default Car Name"},
  {"Name":"Default Car Name"}
]
```

Which lost my property: `TeslaEngineName`.

So how can I serialize derived an object with all properties?

Comment: System.Text.Json only serializes with the type specified by design. You need to use the `Tesla` type when (de)serializing to get the extra property, otherwise you'll only get `Car` properties.

Comment: You can use `List<Tesla>`, as an option

Comment: You say you're converting it to .NET 5, did this work before? If so, which json library did you use? Which platform/runtime did you target? I ask because I doubt this has ever worked.

Comment: Sorry, serialization. You're right, I thought about deserialization. Never mind my previous comment.

Comment: The [suggested method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#polymorphic-serialization) to fix this kind of issue is to use `List<object>` in the types you use for serialization. Or ... stay with Json.net

Answer (score 4):

This is a design feature of System.Text.Json, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-polymorphism) for more details. Your options are:

1. Keep using JSON.Net
2. Use one of the workarounds, in this case use a `List<object>` or cast your list when serialising. For example:

   ```
   var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(cars.Cast<object>());
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   The downside of this option is that it will still not serialise any nested properties of derived classes.

Comment: While it works. But not so ideal. It seems that there is no ideal solution for now. Might need the .NET team to solve it.

Comment: But, this solution can't be used if serialization happens implicitly, e.g. returning `ActionResult<...>` from an ASP.NET Controller. 

Comment: It should be noted that this doesn't change the way properties are serialized; this trick only works on the root object. I've found exactly one way to convince System.Text.Json to respect the runtime type of a property during serialization: its type must be `object`. However, this makes **deserialization** of the property very difficult (clunky custom JsonConverter classes seem to be the only option, and to make matters worse, the JsonConverter is required to include a custom serializer). See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30083

Comment: @Qwertie This question isn't about asp.net, and I did mention your second point too

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem as well when I was generating some JSON for a personal project - I had a recursive polymorphic data model that I wanted turned into JSON, but the presence of sub-objects that were derived types of the root object in the root object made the serializer just spit out the base type's properties for all of the derived types. I fiddled around with a JsonConverter and reflection for a few hours and came up with a sledgehammer solution that did what I needed it to do.

Basically what this is doing is manually walking each object in the graph and serializing each member that is not a reference type  using the default serializer, but upon encountering an instance of a reference type (that is not a string) I dynamically generate a new JsonConverter to handle that type and add it to the "Converters" list, then recursively use that new instance to serialize the sub-object as its true runtime type.

You might be able to use it as a starting point towards a solution that can do what you need.

The converter:

```
/// <summary>
/// Instructs the JsonSerializer to serialize an object as its runtime type and not the type parameter passed into the Write function.
/// </summary>
public class RuntimeTypeJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T>
{    
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]> _knownProps = new Dictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]>(); //cache mapping a Type to its array of public properties to serialize
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, JsonConverter> _knownConverters = new Dictionary<Type, JsonConverter>(); //cache mapping a Type to its respective RuntimeTypeJsonConverter instance that was created to serialize that type. 
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> _knownGenerics = new Dictionary<Type, Type>(); //cache mapping a Type to the type of RuntimeTypeJsonConverter generic type definition that was created to serialize that type

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return typeToConvert.IsClass && typeToConvert != typeof(string); //this converter is only meant to work on reference types that are not strings
    }

    public override T? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref reader, typeToConvert, options); //default read implementation, the focus of this converter is the Write operation
        return (T)deserialized;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {            
        if (value is IEnumerable) //if the value is an IEnumerable of any sorts, serialize it as a JSON array. Note that none of the properties of the IEnumerable are written, it is simply iterated over and serializes each object in the IEnumerable
        {             
            WriteIEnumerable(writer, value, options);
        }
        else if (value != null && value.GetType().IsClass == true) //if the value is a reference type and not null, serialize it as a JSON object.
        {
            WriteObject(writer, value, ref options);    
        }       
        else //otherwise just call the default serializer implementation of this Converter is asked to serialize anything not handled in the other two cases
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the values for an object into the Utf8JsonWriter
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">The writer to write to.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value to convert to Json.</param>
    /// <param name="options">An object that specifies the serialization options to use.</param>
    private void WriteObject(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, ref JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var type = value.GetType();

        //get all the public properties that we will be writing out into the object
        PropertyInfo[] props = GetPropertyInfos(type);

        writer.WriteStartObject();

        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            var propVal = prop.GetValue(value);
            if (propVal == null) continue; //don't include null values in the final graph

            writer.WritePropertyName(prop.Name);
            var propType = propVal.GetType(); //get the runtime type of the value regardless of what the property info says the PropertyType should be

            if (propType.IsClass && propType != typeof(string)) //if the property type is a valid type for this JsonConverter to handle, do some reflection work to get a RuntimeTypeJsonConverter appropriate for the sub-object
            {
                Type generic = GetGenericConverterType(propType); //get a RuntimeTypeJsonConverter<T> Type appropriate for the sub-object
                JsonConverter converter = GetJsonConverter(generic); //get a RuntimeTypeJsonConverter<T> instance appropriate for the sub-object

                //look in the options list to see if we don't already have one of these converters in the list of converters in use (we may already have a converter of the same type, but it may not be the same instance as our converter variable above)
                var found = false;
                foreach (var converterInUse in options.Converters)
                {
                    if (converterInUse.GetType() == generic)
                    {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (found == false) //not in use, make a new options object clone and add the new converter to its Converters list (which is immutable once passed into the Serialize method).
                {
                    options = new JsonSerializerOptions(options);
                    options.Converters.Add(converter);
                }

                JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, propVal, propType, options);
            }
            else //not one of our sub-objects, serialize it like normal
            {
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, propVal);
            }
        }

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or makes RuntimeTypeJsonConverter generic type to wrap the given type parameter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propType">The type to get a RuntimeTypeJsonConverter generic type for.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Type GetGenericConverterType(Type propType)
    {
        Type generic = null;
        if (_knownGenerics.ContainsKey(propType) == false)
        {
            generic = typeof(RuntimeTypeJsonConverter<>).MakeGenericType(propType);
            _knownGenerics.Add(propType, generic);
        }
        else
        {
            generic = _knownGenerics[propType];
        }

        return generic;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or creates the corresponding RuntimeTypeJsonConverter that matches the given generic type defintion.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="genericType">The generic type definition of a RuntimeTypeJsonConverter.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private JsonConverter GetJsonConverter(Type genericType)
    {
        JsonConverter converter = null;
        if (_knownConverters.ContainsKey(genericType) == false)
        {
            converter = (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
            _knownConverters.Add(genericType, converter);
        }
        else
        {
            converter = _knownConverters[genericType];
        }

        return converter;
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all the public properties of a Type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="t"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private PropertyInfo[] GetPropertyInfos(Type t)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] props = null;

        if (_knownProps.ContainsKey(t) == false)
        {
            props = t.GetProperties();
            _knownProps.Add(t, props);
        }
        else
        {
            props = _knownProps[t];
        }

        return props;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the values for an object that implements IEnumerable into the Utf8JsonWriter
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">The writer to write to.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value to convert to Json.</param>
    /// <param name="options">An object that specifies the serialization options to use.</param>
    private void WriteIEnumerable(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray();

        foreach (object item in value as IEnumerable)
        {
            if (item == null) //preserving null gaps in the IEnumerable
            {
                writer.WriteNullValue();
                continue;
            }

            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, item, item.GetType(), options);
        }

        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
```

To use:

```
        var cars = new List<Car>
        {
            new Tesla(),
            new Tesla(),
            new Tesla()
        };

        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
        options.Converters.Add(new RuntimeTypeJsonConverter<object>());

        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(cars, cars.GetType(), options);
```

Answer (score 2):

A (simple) solution that helped me for some polymorphic serialization-support through abusing the object-trick mentioned above.

**PolymorpicConverter**

```
/// <example>
/// <code>
/// [PolymorpicConverter]
/// public Vehicle[] Vehicles { get; set; } = new Vehicle[]
/// {
///   new Car(),
///   new Bicycle()
/// };
/// </code>
/// </example>
/// <remarks>
/// Converter can not be used in <see cref="JsonSerializerOptions.Converters"/> because <see cref="JsonSerializer"/>
/// caches <see cref="JsonConverter"/> by <see cref="JsonConverter.CanConvert"/> which causes recursion.
/// </remarks>
internal sealed class PolymorpicConverter
    : JsonConverter<System.Object>
{

    // https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65664086/system-text-json-serialize-derived-class-property
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0
    // https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2022/02/22/6569/recursive-polymorphic-deserialization-with-system-text-json

    // https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29937 - Support polymorphic serialization through new option
    // https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30083 - JsonSerializer polymorphic serialization and deserialization support
    // https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30969 - [System.Text.Json] serialize/deserialize any object
    // https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30969#issuecomment-535779492
    // https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/54328   - Add polymorphic serialization to System.Text.Json
    // https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/63747 - Developers can use System.Text.Json to serialize type hierarchies securely

    public PolymorpicConverter() { }

    public override bool CanConvert(
        [DisallowNull] Type type)
    {
        return type.IsAssignableTo(typeof(System.Object));
    }

    public override System.Object Read(
        [DisallowNull] ref System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader reader,
        [DisallowNull] Type typeToConvert,
        [AllowNull] System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException($"{nameof(PolymorpicConverter)} only supports serialization.");
    }

    public override void Write(
        [DisallowNull] System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        [DisallowNull] System.Object value,
        [AllowNull] System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, default(System.Object), options);
            return;
        }

        // String is also an Array (of char)
        if (value is System.String stringValue)
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, stringValue, options);
            return;
        }

        // Object-trick
        if (value is System.Collections.IEnumerable enumerable)
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, enumerable.Cast<System.Object>().ToArray(), options);
            return;
        }

        // Object-trick
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, (System.Object)value, options);
    }
}
```

**PolymorpicConverterAttribute**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class PolymorpicConverterAttribute
    : JsonConverterAttribute
{

    public PolymorpicConverterAttribute()
        : base(typeof(PolymorpicConverter))
    { }

}
```

**Unit Test**

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

[TestClass]
public sealed class PolymorpicConverterTests
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void SerializeTest()
    {
        var container = new Container
        {
            Test = "List of Vehicles"
        };
        
        var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(container);

        Assert.IsTrue(json.Contains("Trek"));
        Assert.IsTrue(json.Contains("List of Vehicles"));

        Assert.IsTrue(json.Contains("My Wheels-property"));
        Assert.IsTrue(json.Contains("My Make-property"));
        Assert.IsTrue(json.Contains("My Model-property"));
        Assert.IsTrue(json.Contains("My Manufacturer-property"));
    }

    public class Container
    {

        [PolymorpicConverter] // not required; but to validate possible interferance
        [JsonPropertyName("My Test-property")]
        public System.String Test { get; set; }

        [PolymorpicConverter]
        public Vehicle[] Vehicles { get; set; } = new Vehicle[]
        {
            new Car() { Make = "BMW", Model = "E92" },
            new Bicycle() { Manufacturer = "Trek", }
        };

    }

    public abstract class Vehicle
    {

        [PolymorpicConverter] // not required; but to validate possible interferance
        [JsonPropertyName("My Wheels-property")]
        public System.Int32 Wheels { get; protected set; }

    }

    public class Car
        : Vehicle
    {

        public Car()
        {
            Wheels = 4;
        }

        [PolymorpicConverter] // not required; but to validate possible interferance
        [JsonPropertyName("My Make-property")]
        public System.String Make { get; set; }

        [PolymorpicConverter] // not required; but to validate possible interferance
        [JsonPropertyName("My Model-property")]
        public System.String Model { get; set; }

    }

    public class Bicycle
        : Vehicle
    {

        public Bicycle()
        {
            Wheels = 2;
        }

        [PolymorpicConverter] // not required; but to validate possible interferance
        [JsonPropertyName("My Manufacturer-property")]
        public System.String Manufacturer { get; set; }

    }

}
```

JSON

```
{
   "My Test-property":"List of Vehicles",
   "Vehicles":[
      {
         "My Make-property":"BMW",
         "My Model-property":"E92",
         "My Wheels-property":4
      },
      {
         "My Manufacturer-property":"Trek",
         "My Wheels-property":2
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own converter:

```
public class TeslaConverter : JsonConverter<Car>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type type)
    {
        return typeof(Car).IsAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    public override Car Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        Car value,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {

        if (value is Tesla derivedA)
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, derivedA);
        }
        else if (value is OtherTypeDerivedFromCar derivedB)
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, derivedB);
        }
        else
            throw new NotSupportedException();

    }
}
```

and implement it like so:

```
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            Converters = { new TeslaConverter () }
        };

        var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(doc, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this variant of the function:

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(cars, cars.getType());
```

This is intended behavior and is [documented.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-polymorphism)

Comment: The problem is that nested properties don't get this same treatment, so your options boil down to a custom converter or have everything be object type, which is also bad.