# System.Text.Json serialization not using derived classes

Tags: .net-core, serialization, system.text.json

I have an abstract class named `Extension` which has several derived classes such as `DerivedExtensionA`, `DerivedExtensionB`, etc.

Now I have a list defined as `List<Extension>` which contains the derived classes instances.

Now if I serialize the above list, it only serializes the base class properties that are in `Extension` since the list has the base class `Extension` type. If I define the list as `List<DerivedExtensionA>` and then put only instances of `DerivedExtensionA` in it, then they are serialized fine. But my code is generic which is supposed to accept all types of Extensions, so this isn't a workable solution for me.

So question is ..

How do I keep the list defined as `List<Extension>` and still be able to fully serialize the contained derived class instances that contain ALL their properties ?

Here is a fiddle showing this behavior: https://dotnetfiddle.net/22mbwb

EDIT: Corrected the fiddle URL

Comment: I just corrected the fiddle URL.

Comment: This is [as designed and documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-polymorphism).  You can either 1) Add a `JsonConverter<Extension>` that serializes the derived classes explicitly as shown in [Serialize objects implementing interface with System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66498917/3744182), or 2) serialize your `List<Extension>` via an `IEnumerable<object>` surrogate property as shown in [System.Text.Json serialize derived class property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65664460).

Comment: If you also need to deserialize you will need to add a type discriminator property.  See [Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304/3744182) for many converters that do this.

Comment: Do those questions answer yours also, or do you need more specific help?  [Why does System.Text Json Serialiser not serialise this generic property but Json.NET does?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62033264/3744182) also addresses this problem.

Answer (score 2):

From [How to serialize properties of derived classes with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-polymorphism)

> Serialization of a polymorphic type hierarchy is not supported.

In your fiddle you can use an array of objects:

```
string allExtensionsSerialized =
   JsonSerializer.Serialize((object[])allExtensions.ToArray());
```

This is the hack I used recently:

```
public record MyType(
   // This nonsense is here because System.Text.Json does not support normal polymorphic serialisation
   [property: JsonIgnore] List<X> Messages))
{
   // This nonsense is here because System.Text.Json does not support normal polymorphic serialisation
   [JsonPropertyName("Messages")]
   public object[] MessagesTrick => Messages.ToArray();
```

For deserialisation, I decided used `JsonDocument.Parse` inside a dedicated `FromJson(string json)` method. This works OK, for me, in this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I ended up changing the definition of the list from `List<Extension>` to `List<object>`, and the behavior was corrected. This might not be a workable solution for everyone reading this, but it's fine for me so that's why I'm adding my own answer.