# Serialization -> how to change Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#

I discovered a different behaviour when I want to serialize an object of type **INTERFACE** in System.Text.Json.

```
public class ITestClass
{
}

public class TestClass : ITestClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Newtonsoft.Json:

```
var result1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testClass));
var result2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result1); // {"MyProperty":5}
```

System.Text.Json:

```
var result1 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(testClass);
var result2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result1); // {}
```

How can I get the same result in System.Text.Json like in Newtonsoft.Json?
I want to get:
{"MyProperty":5}
not:
{}

Comment: May be related to : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0 And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65664086/system-text-json-serialize-derived-class-property

Comment: @DragandDrop: You'll get this behavior if `testClass` is declared as `ITestClass` instead of `TestClass`. I'm assuming this important detail was left out of the question by mistake...

Comment: yes, it is very important, it has to by INTERFACE

Comment: Still covered by SO related question : 
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/65664460/6560478
  var t1 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize ((object)input); // https://stackoverflow.com/a/70759454/6560478
  var t2 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize (input, input.GetType());

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.Text.Json serialize derived class property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65664086/system-text-json-serialize-derived-class-property)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var result 2 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(testClass);
```

Comment: but I need to byte[], not string as a result

Answer (score 0):

OK, I know. I need to cast an object of type interface to "object":

```
var result1 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes((object)testClass);
var result2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result1); // {"MyProperty":5}
```